# Highlight color change for "Select all"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JavaScript to change the highlight color on the table using the form below. Default color is green, and I can pick the color I want by clicking the color button. This code works only on inputs with `class="selector"`. I wanted this function to work for inputs with `class="all"` too, so I duplicated the code and changed `$('.selector')` to => `$('.all')` in the second copy. but I couldn't get the result I wanted, the code doesn't work for `class="all"` selection. I would like color change to be possible for "Select All" too.Any ideas how to achieve this? please. thanks.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hfh6smf8/

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
  $('.selector').on('click', function(e) {
    var checked = this.name;
    var selectedColor = '';

    if (this.checked) {
      selectedColor = $('#nextColor').val();

      }
    $('td').filter(function() {
      return this.textContent == checked;
    }).css('background-color', selectedColor);
  });
});
```

HTML form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />SelectAll</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="M" class="selector" />M</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="n" class="selector" />n</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="nn" class="selector" />nn</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="R" class="selector" />R</label>
</form>
```

Comment: you need to do another click event for `.all` which will loop all the `.selector` class and perform the color change each, make a function with parameter and move your code into it, so that it minimize the code to loop and change the color

Comment: I tried the same script with  <code>.all</code>. It didn't change the result.

Comment: not really sure what you mean on that

Comment: $(function () {
 $('.all')   I made this change.

Comment: can attach a jsfiddle, to ease the troubleshoot?sample snipper, https://jsfiddle.net/r83gj8sy/

Comment: here: https://jsfiddle.net/hfh6smf8/ sorry, i was a bit late.

Comment: Normally Select all works for default color (green) but I couldn't run it on fiddle for some reason.

Comment: You are filtering based on td of each cell `$('td').filter(function() {...}`. All other checkboxes would work because you have named each checkbox with the same names as your data. You need a function that would loop through all the cells when 'Select All' is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/hfh6smf8/7/

is this what you try to achieve? if yes, it will be easy if you had put out all the relevant html
and also, did you want to check all the checkbox?

```
$('.all').on('click', function(e) {
    var checked = this.name;
    var selectedColor = '';

    if (this.checked) {
      selectedColor = $('#nextColor').val();

      }
    $('td').css('background-color', selectedColor);
  });
```

this is to answer your another question, you need to know how to play with the `selector`, it will help you a lot, as this is just sample which can achieve what you want to do, you can make it more specific selector

https://jsfiddle.net/5z7zbaq2/2/
change

```
$('td').css('background-color', selectedColor);
```

to

```
 $('#form1').find('td').css('background-color', selectedColor);
```

Comment: Yes, exactly.  interesting with a little change it works. thanks @Se0ng11

Comment: It does this however. https://jsfiddle.net/5z7zbaq2/ It selects all data on the table even if they are not in the form.

Comment: Thanks @Se0ng11. You are a great help.